# How to enable administrative functionality for batch job status notifcation in Spring XD distributed runtime system

Tags: spring-xd, spring-batch-admin, crontrigger

We have small cluster.In which spring xd distributed runtime architecture is component for ETL.
 We have scheduled batch job in it using cron.But when job fails or interrupted,We are not getting notified over named channel or Email and is that possible to trigger batch jobs by sending messages to named channels?

**Currently,Running on Following Environment:**

Spring XD Distributed Runtime - 1.2.1

Hadoop Distribution  - PHD3.0

Any help on it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write your own step that handles the notification for you. So in your batch flow you will configure some steps that only get executed when your other steps fail.

Something like...

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="stepA">
        <next on="*" to="stepB" />
        <next on="FAILED" to="NotifyErrorEmail" />
    </step>
    <step id="stepB".. />
    <step id="NotifyErrorEmail" />
</job>
```

You can read more in [Spring Batch Configuring Steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Comment: Thank you, For direction gave us.